# How to find all the possible k integers which sum of them equals to a certain number in R

Tags: r, algorithm

suppose I have a integer `n` and `k`, I need find all the possible combinations of `k` integers which sum to `n`. I was wondering to how do I implement this efficiently.

right now, what I am doing is super slow, I created `kth` cartesian product of a sequence from 1 to n. And then loop over all the possible combinations to check if it satisfy the sum.Below is my code.

first get k cartesian product

```
cart = function(v,k){
  x = v
  f = v
  for(i in 1:(k-1)){
    f = merge(f,x,all=T)
    f = as.matrix(f)
    colnames(f) = NULL
  }
  return(f)
}
```

v is the sequence from 1 to n and k is the integer

then loop over

```
combine = cart(v=seq(1,n),k=k)
sum = 0
for(i in 1:dim(combine)[1]){
  if(sum(combine[i,])==n){
    sum = sum + sum(combine[i,])
  }
}
```

this is super slow and I was wondering is there any faster way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edited based on clarification of question in comments:**

Sounds like you are wanting all compositions, rather than all partitions of the integer `n`. (Two sequences differing only in the order of their terms are considered to be the same **partition**, but different **compositions**.)

To get compositions, use the `compositions()` function from the **partitions** package:

```
library(partitions)
compositions(4, 3, include.zero=FALSE)
#           
# [1,] 2 1 1
# [2,] 1 2 1
# [3,] 1 1 2
```

---

**Original answer, left in place until the package author has had a chance to see it:**

If I correctly understand your question, you could use `restrictedparts()` from the **partitions** package.

For example:

```
library(partitions)

restrictedparts(9,4)
#                                         
# [1,] 9 8 7 6 5 7 6 5 4 5 4 3 6 5 4 4 3 3
# [2,] 0 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 2 3 3 1 2 3 2 3 2
# [3,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 2
# [4,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2

## Or, for partitions employing only non-zero integers
restrictedparts(9,4,include.zero=FALSE)
#                 
# [1,] 6 5 4 4 3 3
# [2,] 1 2 3 2 3 2
# [3,] 1 1 1 2 2 2
# [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

Due to a minor bug in the second to last line of `restrictedparts`, it can throw an error when the given restriction allows just one partition. I've sent a proposed fix to the package author, but in the meantime you can get around this by setting the function argument `decreasing=FALSE`:

```
## Throws an error
restrictedparts(4,3,include.zero=FALSE)
# Error in class(x) <- "matrix" : 
# invalid to set the class to matrix unless the dimension attribute is of # length 2 (was 0)

## Works just fine
restrictedparts(4,3,include.zero=FALSE,decreasing=FALSE)
#       
# [1,] 1
# [2,] 1
# [3,] 2
```

Comment: thanks, Josh, but I got an error when implement restrictedparts(4,3,include.zero = F), thanks

Comment: @weikangduan Nice catch. That's due to a bug in `restrictedparts()`. See my edit for an easy workaround.

Comment: Hi @Josh, thanks. But the result I am looking for is 1 1 2, 1 2 1 and 2 2 1. Is there anyway to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @weikangduan Those are called 'compositions', and you can get them by doing `partitions::compositions(4, 3, include.zero=FALSE)`,

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R method using `combn`. Lets say you have the integers 1 through 12 and you want to find all of the sets of 5 numbers that sum to 20.

```
myGroups <- combn(1:12, 5)
mysums <- combn(1:12, 5, FUN=sum, simplify=TRUE)

myAnswers <- myGroups[, mysums == 20]
```

This returns a matrix where the columns are the sets of numbers:

```
myAnswers
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3    4    4    4    4
[4,]    4    5    6    5    6    5    5
[5,]   10    9    8    8    7    7    6
```

This will be easy to wrap up in a function. In the function below, x is the input vector, which I set as 1:12 in the example above, and k and n are defined in the OP's question.

```
myfunction <- function(x, k, n) {
  myGroups <- combn(x, k)
  mysums <- combn(x, k, FUN=sum, simplify=TRUE)

  myGroups[, mysums == n]
}
```

*Note*
This method assumes that each entry in x will be used once in the calculation, so on the integers 0:9 that add up to 9 using 4 of them, `myfunction` returns:

```
myfunction(0:9, 4, 9)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    2
[3,]    2    3    3
[4,]    6    5    4
```

*Note*
If the goal is the allow for repeated use of these integers, we simply must adjust what we feed to `myfunction`. Note that this will result in duplicated output of sets, since order matters to `combn`.

---

If repeated integers will be involved, the use of `combn` has to be modified to return a list so we can use `unique` to drop duplicate sets:

```
myfunctionDupes <- function(x, k, n) {
  # return list instead of matrix, with elements sorted
  myGroups <- lapply(combn(x, k, simplify=FALSE), sort)
  # find duplicates
  dupes <- duplicated(myGroups)
  # subset summations to those where myGroups is not a duplicate
  mysums <- combn(x, k, FUN=sum, simplify=TRUE)[!dupes]
  # subset myGroups to the unique values then those with sums == n
  myGroups <- (myGroups[!dupes])[mysums == n]
  # return a matrix
  do.call(cbind, myGroups)
}
```

This takes a little while to run on @josh-obrien's example, but it produces the same result:

```
myfunctionDupes(rep(0:9, 4), 4, 9)
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     2
[2,]    1    1    1    1    0    2    2    0    0     3     0     0     2     2     1     1     1     2
[3,]    2    3    4    1    1    3    2    2    3     3     4     0     3     2     2     3     1     2
[4,]    6    5    4    7    8    4    5    7    6     3     5     9     3     4     5     4     6     3
```

Comment: Why restrict `x` to anything less than `1:(n-k+1)` ?

Comment: I got an error for Error in combn(x, k, FUN = sum, simplify = TRUE) : 
  'FUN' must be a function or NULL , I was wondering where went wrong, thanks

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry. Which part restricts x? I think the function will technically take any vector (though will only work on integers).

Comment: @weikangduan Try copying and pasting my answer. I just tried both of the versions in a fresh R session and they worked.

Comment: I just figured we'd want all possibles :-) .  BTW you don't need the `which` . `R` will operate on logical vectors.

Comment: I can't get your code to work with   9,4 as in Josh's example.  Something goes wrong with smaller numbers.  Oh:  your solution does not allow repeated values, and his does.  I think yours is not what the OP wants

Comment: @lmo, I think that I didn't make my question super clear, what I want to generate is, for instance, I need to find k integers, where all of them are smaller than n, and their sum should equal to n. For instance, if n =4, and k =3, then the result I want is 1, 1, 2; 2, 1, 1; 1, 2, 1;

Comment: See my last update, which contains this as a possibility. The only thing is that you would have to feed `functionDupes` the x vector that would allow for all possible combinations. See, for example, how I constructed the vector in that example.

Comment: @lmo liked your answer