# Matrix construction in R with condition on columns

Tags: r, matrix

I want to construct a matrix with 3 rows and 200 columns.

I want each row to have the values from `0` to `200`, but I also want this matrix to contain only the columns where these 3 rows sum up to 200.

It would be something like this:

```
0   1   2   ... 200 
1   2   3   ... X 
199 197 195 ... Y
```

I guess that could be a possible start, but I really don't know how I could do it.

I was trying to do maybe 3 nested for loops but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: I gave an answer that returns all 3-way combinations of numbers that sum to 200, but re-reading your question I'm not sure that's what you want. Why did you decide this matrix would have 200 columns? (There are far more than 200 ways to add three numbers up to get 200)

Comment: You are completely right, it's because of my poor understanding of this matrix construction.

Comment: OK: maybe you could explain more about what you're using the matrix for?

Comment: Take a look at the [following post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081651/how-to-find-all-the-possible-k-integers-which-sum-of-them-equals-to-a-certain-nu/38082278). I think there is sufficient overlap so that it should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in two steps, with the `expand.grid` function (which generates all combinations of vectors), and then column-wise filtering:

```
m <- t(as.matrix(expand.grid(0:200, 0:200, 0:200)))
m <- m[, colSums(m) == 200]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wanted my rows to have the values from 0 to 200, but if I do `max(m[1,])` it's equal to `65`. That's is the hard part (for me at least).

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you. So am I safe to assume that this matrix has in its columns all the ways to add up 3 numbers from 0 to 200 that sum 200?

Comment: @JavierM88 The second one (the `expand.grid` solution) does, yes. Note that it includes duplicates in different orders- for example, it includes `0+0+200`, `0+200+0`, and `200+0+0` as separate columns

Comment: Yes, duplicate values on the rows is what I wanted as well!